# Stylus on the touch-screen of a laptop that can detect "pressure", "tilting" and alike

Tags: windows, laptop, touchscreen, adobe-illustrator, stylus

My laptop (Lenovo) has a touch screen. I want to use a professional stylus for drawing in Adobe Illustrator on Windows. I was wondering whether or not the "pressure", "titling", etc are detectable on the touch screen of the laptop!?

I'm not talking about the ones that come with a tablet pad, but instead I want to draw directly on the touch screen of the laptop while also have the "pressure", "tilting", etc being detected.

What are they called, if such a technology exists? Please shed some lights on the issue.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Questions seeking for hardware shopping recommendations are off-topic because they are often relevant only to the question author at the time the question was asked and tend to become obsolete quickly.

Comment: @EricF Hi, Actually I don't know if such a technology even exists!!! I'm not looking for any recommendation of hardware shopping, I'm just wondering what are they called, if they exist!!!

Comment: https://mspoweruser.com/microsofts-new-surface-pen-now-available-for-pre-order-supports-4096-pressure-levels-and-tilt-detection/ Apparently so for pen form and it looks like there are a few interesting patents out there like this one https://www.google.com/patents/US8638320

Comment: @EricF Thanks for the link, but does it work with my laptop? (my laptop is not "Surface", certainly!)

Comment: This one possibly? https://www.artrage.com/artrage-android-supported-stylus-features/

Comment: @EricF I really appreciate it :) But it seems to be working on Android OS only (and perhaps brand specific!!) while I work with Adobe Illustrator on Windows, so the stylus also needs to be compatible with Windows!